# phantomjs page.onResourceRecieved resource.body

Tags: node.js, linux, phantomjs

I am trying to use phantomjs on my ec2-instance linux based.
I need the ability to listen to all network navigations and get the resource.body.
I saw that this feature was enabled and disabled many times. is there any stable release which has this feature? (without the need to build the dll by myself)

Comment: Where did you see that this was enabled? I haven't seen a single official build where this was possible.

Comment: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/434d4e0101a540525e8f89a657ea553fb38b040b

Comment: it was enabled but after a while someone noticed it breaks the web sockets and then it was reverted.